# Some code is not executing with UIPanGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uipangesturerecognizer

So I have this code to move the `UIImageView` around if it hits 3/4 the screen from the bottom it dismiss the view controller but when I try to set the next image or previous one the code doesn't execute is there any clue ?

```
func dismissImageView(panGesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

    if panGesture.state == .ended {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25) {
            self.imageView.frame = self.scrollView.frame
            self.imageView.alpha = 1.0
        }
    } else {

        if self.scrollView.zoomScale == 1.0 {

            let scrollViewFrame = self.scrollView.frame
            let translation = self.panGesture.translation(in: self.scrollView)

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25) {
                self.imageView.frame.origin.x = translation.x
                self.imageView.frame.origin.y = translation.y

                if self.lastImageFramePosition != nil {
                    if translation.y > self.lastImageFramePosition {
                        self.imageView.alpha -= 0.01
                    } else {
                        self.imageView.alpha += 0.01
                    }
                }
            }

            self.lastImageFramePosition = translation.y

            if self.imageView.center.y >= ((scrollViewFrame.size.height * 3) / 4) {
                self.dismissImageViewNormally()
            } else if translation.x >= 150 {
                self.nextImage() // if I print something out it prints but the next code doesn't execute
            } else if translation.x <= -150 {
                self.previousImage()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

// nextImage

```
func nextImage() {

    if selectedImage != (self.images.count - 1) {
        self.goToImage(index: (selectedImage + 1))
    }
}
```

// goToImage(index:)

```
func goToImage(index: Int) {

    if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: images[index].path) {
        if sharedFileManager.getFileType(url: images[index]) == kUTTypeImage {
            do {
                let imageData = try Data(contentsOf: images[index])
                let image = UIImage(data: imageData)!
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
                    self.imageView.alpha = 0.0
                    self.imageView.image = image
                    self.imageView.alpha = 1.0
                })
                self.imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
                self.selectedImage = index
                self.navigationItem.title = self.images[selectedImage].deletingPathExtension().lastPathComponent
                self.updateNavigationButtons()

            } catch {}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is responsible for issue   -  if self.imageView.center.y >= ((scrollViewFrame.size.height * 3) / 4) {

Comment: no it does not look like this. I commented it and still the same issue.

Comment: can you share self.nextImage()

Comment: Now add print statement like print("1"), print("2").... into your code for next image and go to image... above, inside and below each if statements and see how many steps are printed in console

Comment: I can't tell from your code, but make sure you are setting one pan gesture *for each* image view. You cannot assign a single gesture to more than one view.

Comment: OMG sorry my mistake, I figured it out my images array was clearing its objects there were no images to switch to. Thanks for your delightful help guys.

Comment: Also you should deal with the .canceled state for the gestureRecognizer in the same way that you deal with .ended or you can have the view stuck in an unexpected state.

Comment: Thanks for bringing that to my attention (Y)